# Kibana - Reporting feature is missing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, reporting, elastic-stack

I have installed Kibana version **6.5** . I have opted for the 30 day free trial and enabled the x-pack security options.

Through Kibana UI i have created an user and assigned 2 roles which is needed for reporting- **kibana_user** and **reporting_user**. Now I login through this new user and don't find Reporting option on the Dashboard.

It's the same behaviour even if i log in using the **elastic** user which has superuser role.
Am i missing something?

I see a log in Kibana startup saying reporting plugin status is ready.

> log   [11:11:32.456] [info][status][plugin:reporting@6.5.3] Status
>   changed from yellow to green - Ready

And i can see a reporting option in Management section; which shows as empty because no report is generated yet.

Comment: I see a similar question here- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-6-3-reporting-option-not-available/144640 which is not answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable the reporting feature in your `kibana.yml` configuration file and restart your Kibana node:

```
xpack.reporting.enabled: true
```

Also note that you will only see the Reporting button when you're in the Discover view and using a saved search or on a visualization or a dashboard. See [point 2 here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/reporting-getting-started.html)

> 2. Open the dashboard, visualization, or saved search you want to include in the report.

Another thing worth noting is that in 6.5 the Reporting button is located within the "Share" button. You'll be able to export a saved search as CSV. Same thing for dashboard, inside the Share button you'll see "PDF report"

Comment: Isn't that option to be set in kibana.yml ? I have set it in kibana as per this doc https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.5/reporting-settings-kb.html#reporting-kibana-server-settings

Comment: Mistyped sorry, yes, that's a kibana setting

Comment: I do have a dashboard created. But i see the reporting option only on the management section. Nowhere else.

Comment: Can you create a saved search in the discover view, then switch to it. Do you see the Reporting button?

Comment: Also note that in 6.5 the Reporting button is located within the "Share" button. You'll be able to export a saved search as CSV. Same thing for dashboard, inside the Share button you'll see "PDF report"

Comment: Thanks @Val ! Just figured this out! Can you add this as the answer.  I wonder why the documentation is not updated yet.

Comment: Done, glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Pdf reporting feature is not available in the basic license.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/generate-pdf-report-missing/190492